# C# Regex explicitly match string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match only words from A-Z and a-z with an optional period at the end. This is the code I have so far:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(word, @"[A-Za-z]\.?")
```

This means the following should return true: `test`, `test.`.

The following should return false: `t3st`, `test..`, `.`, .

Right now this regex returns true for everything.

Comment: you want digits too? try: `@"^[A-Za-z0-9]\.?$"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `regex`:

```
@"^[A-Za-z]+\.?$"
```

*Boundary matchers*

- ^ means  beginning of a line
- $    means end of a line

*Greedy quantifier*

- [A-Za-z]+ means [A-Za-z], one or more times

Answer (score 0):

Your regex only asks for a single letter followed by an optional period.  Since all your words start with a letter, that regex returns true.

Notice the + in Prince John Wesley's answer - that says to use one *or more* letters, so it'll "eat" all the letters in the word, stopping at a non-letter.  Then the \.? tests for an optional period.

I don't think the ^ and $ are needed in this case.

You might also want to include the hyphen and the single-quote in your regex; otherwise you'll have problems with hyphenated words and contractions.

That may get messy; some words have more than one hyphen:  "port-of-call" or "coat-of-arms", for example.  Very rarely you'll find a word with more than one quote:  "I'd've" for "I would have".  They're rare enough you can probably forget about 'em.   (oops!  there's a word that *starts* with a quote...  :)

Comment: Without the ^ and $, the regex would still return true for anything containing a letter.